# Google spreadsheet: Intercept calls before trigger (event) open

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, eventtrigger

I have a code into a spreadsheet (A) that does a copy of a sheet  from another spreadsheet (B) the is activate from a trigger onOpen.

But trigger onOpen starts after 5 or 6 seconds, so a user can do some changes into the sheet.
I would like to keep my sheet for those 10 seconds too.
Have you an idea? I'm looking how to intercept calls before trigger open but I don't find documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can install a onEditSs edit trigger on B (dont use the simple onEdit, instead install one).
From there copy to A whenever the range changes (keep the last one copied on cache to minimize writes).
This way A is always up to date even without opening it.

Comment: ok, this is an idea, but always I have had the problem of the 5 or 6 seconds when an User opens the file.

Comment: I dont get that delay. Ive done q similar sync from A to B and B always updated under 1s of changing A